# TeamCity: run all tests after a failure

Tags: teamcity

after upgrade to Teamcity 8 I have an issue with failed builds. I have a project with Maven modules A, B, C, D. Build is failed because of the error in D. I commit change in module A, Teamcity executes only tests in A (there are no new failures), skip module D (if it doesn't depend on A) and mark build as green. It is ok when build is green already, but how to ask Teamcity to run tests for modules, that failed in previous build.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling "incremental" maven build feature:

> Edit Configuration -> Build Steps -> Maven Step -> clear "Build only modules affected by changes"

(click "Show advanced" if this option is not visible).

If this feature is not used, then it is Maven that decidec which tests to run. Try adding a `clean` goal at the beginning of goals list to force rebuild (and re-test) of all modules.